# How to convert Object array into String arrray and split individual elements from it?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

The following is the question prompt: 
Create a hash with the following information in the format -

countryname => `"capital:population:currency name"` create at least 5 records.

Print the details of the country having the largest population
Print the currency name of those countries where capital name starts with "L".

For doing this, I was thinking of populating records with `put()`, converting the values of hashmap into an array, splitting the array with `":"` delimeter, and doing a loop to figure out largest value from the respective column.

I was wondering whether that would be the best way of doing it, or there would be a better approach. If that way is ideal, I am having trouble converting the `Object [] countryValues` (in the code below) into a String array, so I can use the split function on it.

I expect this to split the values with `":"` delimeter.

```
HashMap<String,String> countrydata = new HashMap<String, String>();

    countrydata.put("USA", "Washington DC:323,000,000:Dollar");
    countrydata.put("Thailand", "Bangkok:69,000,000:Baht");
    countrydata.put("Vietnam", "Hanoi:93,000,000:Dong");
    countrydata.put("Laos", "Lientiane:7,000,000:Dollar");
    countrydata.put("Belize", "Belmopan:370,000:Dollar");

     Object [] countryValues = countrydata.keySet().toArray();

     for (int i=0; i<countryValues.length; i++){
        String [] splitted = countryValues[i].split(":");
     }

     for (int j=0; j<splitted.length; j++){
         System.out.println(splitted[i]);
     }
```

Error:

Method `split(String)` is undefined for type Object.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine the code together:

```
HashMap<String,String> countrydata = new HashMap<String, String>();

countrydata.put("USA", "Washington DC:323,000,000:Dollar");
countrydata.put("Thailand", "Bangkok:69,000,000:Baht");
countrydata.put("Vietnam", "Hanoi:93,000,000:Dong");
countrydata.put("Laos", "Lientiane:7,000,000:Dollar");
countrydata.put("Belize", "Belmopan:370,000:Dollar");
```

So you have a Map where the keys are country names, and the values are various information as strings, to be split.

```
Object [] countryValues = countrydata.keySet().toArray();
```

So you're create an array of objects, and each object in the array is a **key** of the map: a country name.

```
for (int i=0; i<countryValues.length; i++){
   String [] splitted = countryValues[i].split(":");
```

and you're thus trying to split the keys, instead of the values. Moreover, there is no need at all to transform a collection into an array to do a for loop. You can iterate on the collection directly:

```
for (String value: countrydata.values()) {
    // split the value
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank You so much for your detailed reply. 
Ok, so I tried to use the for loop as you mentioned. This is what I have:
`for (String value: countrydata.values()) {</br>
      String [] arrayValue = value.split(":");</br>
  }</br>
  
  for (int i = 0; i<arrayValue.length; i++){</br>
   System.out.println(arrayValue[i]);</br>

Comment: Sorry, i was trying to figure out the formatting. Also, once I split the value with that iteration, I will be assigning the elements (ie. {"Washington DC", "323,000,000", "Dollar" and so on} to an array right? That is what I tried to do in the code above. However, it says my array (arrayValue) is not a resolved variable when I try to print one of the values out of it.  

Lastly, if the individual elements are indeed stored in a separate array, how would I find out the highest population value? since I do not really have the connection of the value to the index of country name, right?

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, I've been trying to figure this out for a while, but am struggling!!

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is this line:

```
Object [] countryValues = countrydata.keySet().toArray();
```

In addition to being named a wrong thing (it's `countryKeys` or `countryNames`, not `countryValues`) it makes an array of `Object` type rather than a `String` array.

You do not need `countryValues` at all: instead, navigate `entrySet` of your hash map like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String,String> e : countrydata.entrySet()) {
    String name = e.getKey();
    String data = e.getValue();
    ...
}
```

If you'd like to take this a little further, make a class `CountryData` with four properties (name, capital, population, and currency), create instances of this class, and put them in your map. Change map's type to `Map<String,CountryData>`. This way you would not need to do split repeatedly if you need to do some additional processing.

Answer (score 0):

Using java 8 stream it will very simple and efficient such operation as below, just define simple POJO for Country.

```
        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();

    countries.add(new Country("USA", "Washington DC", 323000000L, "Dollar"));
    countries.add(new Country("Thailand", "Bangkok", 69000000L, "Baht"));
    countries.add(new Country("Vietnam", "Hanoi", 93000000L, "Dong"));
    countries.add(new Country("Laos", "Lientiane", 7000000L, "Dollar"));
    countries.add(new Country("Belize", "Belmopan", 370000L, "Dollar"));

    Set<String> filteredCountries = countries.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getCapital().startsWith("L")).map(p -> p.getName())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    Country maxPopulationCountry = countries.stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getPopulation())).get();

    System.out.println("Max Population Country Details : " + maxPopulationCountry);
    System.out.println("Countries with Capital starts with L : " + filteredCountries);
```